# LaTeX toc after each section

Tags: latex

How can I add a table of contents after the beginning of a chapter?

See [Master Thesis](http://diuf.unifr.ch/people/fuhrer/studproj/rohrer/download/GraphicalAspectModelEditor_GAME.pdf) , page 1.

Btw, does anyone know what LaTeX documentclass / style this is ?! Looks really nice.

Comment: voting to migrate on [tex.se]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the *minitoc* package does what you want:
http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/contents/minitoc.pdf